# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, weblogic12c, ojdbc

I work on a java web application. I use `Weblogic 12c` in my machine. The database (`Oracle`) is installed in another host.

Recently the database version got upgraded to `11.2.0.4.0` and `java` got upgraded from `6` to `7` (both my `weblogic` and `jdk` installed are of `32-bit` versions).

So, I'm attempting to upgrade the `JDBC driver` version from `ojdbc14` to `ojdbc6`. I learnt that this has to be done by copying `ojdbc6.jar` to `$JAVA_HOME/jdk/jre/lib/ext` location.

After copying the `jar`, I tried to restart the services of weblogic managed nodes and got this exception with stacktrace-

```
####<Feb 9, 2017 6:58:29 AM CST> <Error> <Deployer> <MACHINE_001> <server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1486645109723> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "sample-ear [Version=1]".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Exception activating module: EJBModule(sample-question-service-ejb-1.0.jar)


Unable to deploy EJB: TriggeredEventEB from sample-question-service-ejb-1.0.jar:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection


    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.activate(EJBModule.java:479)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.activate(ScopedModuleDriver.java:206)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:97)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:145)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:192)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:369)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:261)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:246)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:186)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:94)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:219)
    at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:190)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory$1.run(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory.getWrapper(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:161)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.newConnection(Driver.java:974)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.createLocalConnection(Driver.java:340)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.connect(Driver.java:175)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnectionInternal(RmiDataSource.java:553)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:518)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:511)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.cmp.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceManager.getConnection(RDBMSPersistenceManager.java:4050)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.cmp.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceManager.verifyDatabaseType(RDBMSPersistenceManager.java:4272)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.cmp.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceManager.setup(RDBMSPersistenceManager.java:245)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEntityManager.setupPM(BaseEntityManager.java:299)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEntityManager.setup(BaseEntityManager.java:252)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.DBManager.setup(DBManager.java:154)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.ClientDrivenBeanInfoImpl.initCacheManager(ClientDrivenBeanInfoImpl.java:1018)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EntityBeanInfoImpl.initCacheManager(EntityBeanInfoImpl.java:788)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.ClientDrivenBeanInfoImpl.activate(ClientDrivenBeanInfoImpl.java:961)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EntityBeanInfoImpl.activate(EntityBeanInfoImpl.java:223)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.activate(EJBDeployer.java:963)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.activate(EJBModule.java:470)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.activate(ScopedModuleDriver.java:206)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:97)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:145)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:192)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:369)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:261)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:246)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:186)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:94)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>
```

Should I copy the ojdbc6.jar in the machine where my web application is installed (This is currently what I've done)? Or should I copy it in the machine where the Oracle database is installed?

I'm trying to find anything that I'm missing here to successfully deploy the ejb jar. Any leads on this would be of great help.

=========================================================================

**UPDATE:**

I have restarted all managed servers, including the admin server. But that didn't still work.

But I observed one thing. The `sample-question-service-ejb-1.0.jar` is an old one and was created using `jdk1.4`. I verified this by exploding the jar that was in the target folder, ran this command for one of the class files and got the result `48`

`javap -verbose MyClass | findstr "major"`

```
Java 1.2 uses major version 46
Java 1.3 uses major version 47
Java 1.4 uses major version 48
Java 5 uses major version 49
Java 6 uses major version 50
Java 7 uses major version 51
Java 8 uses major version 52
```

Does that mean that I should compile and generate the `jar` file in such a way that I should get `"major"` version as `50` or `51` or something?